# How to make a ByteArray unmodified in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Is there a way to make `ByteArray` unmodifiable in Kotlin?

Like with collections `Collections.unmodifiableList(byteList)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ByteArray` maps to `byte[]` when compiled to the JVM, and the JVM has no support for unmodifiable arrays. You can wrap a `ByteArray` into a class that holds the array in a property and does not provide any APIs for modifying it.

Comment: If you'd return it you'd still get the reference though, right? So you'd need to use the `clone()` method if you want to retrieve the values... Wrapping it in a special class with a getter by index is generally not a good idea.